# TFS - msbuild - fnmatch where filename doesn't contain character

Tags: tfs, msbuild, fnmatch

I'm setting up a build in TFS. In the MSBuild step, it allows wildcards for the project name (like `**/*.csproj`). I'm assuming that it accepts fnmatch syntax like other fields in TFS.

I want to build all projects that don't contain the number "6" in the project name (because they are using .NET 6)

I would expect `**/*!(6)*.csproj` to work, but no dice.

I've tried a few different combinations but can't seem to get it to work.
A few of the things I've tried:

- `**/*!(6)*.csproj`
- `**/*([a-zA-Z0-57-9.]).csproj`
- `**/[a-zA-Z0-57-9.]*.csproj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the time of writing this answer the current version of the [Azure Pipelines MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) is v1 and fnmatch syntax is not supported by the task.

The [Azure Pipelines DotNetCoreCLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) does support fnmatch syntax and MSBuild can be run via the dotnet command.

Something like the following should work (but note that I have not tested this example):

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet msbuild'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'msbuild'
    projects: '**/*!(6)*.csproj'
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realize that you could run `dotnet msbuild` that's super helpful!